# Radio/Dish sockets (ZeroMQ) with java

Tags: java, stream, udp, zeromq

I try to build a streaming communication between two nodes.

So, after reading some articles and advises, I decided to work with ZeroMQ sockets (I had a small experience with those sockets). I found that there are two types of sockets for this (Radio/Dish), that ensure the UDP communication between two nodes. The problem that I found that this is only existing in draft versions. I search for versions having that in JAVA, but I didn't find anything.

Has anyone of you tried to implement a such type of communication and can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Has anyone of you tried to implement a such type of communication and can help me?

Start with a classical `PUB / SUB` pair-of-Archetypes, these are always present in all versions.

Independently of this, you may use UDP-based transport-class via a choice of **`epgm://`** :

> <sub>...*"Encapsulated PGM" or EPGM where PGM datagrams are encapsulated inside UDP datagrams (the **`epgm`** transport)*...</sub>

That should be also present in all versions of (well documented since ever) ZMTP/RFC-compliant ZeroMQ-bindings for Java.